# Appcelerator Titanium or PhoneGap for instagram like app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, titanium, appcelerator

I'm planning an app like Instagram for android and iOS with the following features that access mobile's native features like

- Camera
- User and device info
- Social account features etc

I'm a web developer of HTML,JS,CSS & PHP. 
I'm trying to create the app using a app framework. 
When I did some research I found PhoneGap & Titanium

Now confused about choosing one after reading mixed reviews about both.

I dont want to pay for a framework (Appcelerator Titanium has limitations on commercial apps & charges $200/month ?)

Please suggest me a better framework which will work better with mobile camera and other features also comes free.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must have missed this part of the help section : "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator actually has a completely free version, its just not as user friendly, but it works great and allows use of the Camera, etc..